# LibreOffice Calc sort rows by column comparison

Tags: sorting, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to sort rows based on two columns matching.

For example, in the following table, two users rate the same books. In sorting the example table below, `Book 2` should come first, and `Book 4` second, because the user's ratings both match.

```
  BOOK     USER A     USER B  
 Book 1      4.5        3.5
 Book 2      2.0        2.0
 Book 3      5.0        3.5
 Book 4      3.0        3.0
```

The remaining which did not match, would be in ascending order based on `USER A` ratings (although this isn't the important bit really).

I can use the basic Sort - sorting `Book` and `USER A` by `USER A` ascending, then sort `USER B` ascending separately, and will all match up again with the correct ratings for the correct books, and as I want it. But I need a more functional way of doing this.

Mainly so I can copy the sorted data to a new sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not certain if this is "a more functional way of doing this" but assuming something like :

```
  |   A    |   B    |    C         
------------------------------
1 | BOOK     USER A   USER B    
2 | Book 1      4.5      3.5    
3 | Book 2      2.0      2.0    
4 | Book 3      5.0      3.5    
5 | Book 4      3.0      3.0
```

If the maximum rating is 5 it can be solved easily with a very simple formula in the column `D` :

```
=IF(B2-C2=0;-5+B2;B2)
```

Basically it checks the difference between the columns `B` and `C`.  If they are equals it will return a negative value based on the difference with the maximum. If not we use the rating from User A.

You can then sort the whole range (ascending) based on column `D`.  You should get the result you want.